# How to open a directory path with spaces in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to pass source and destination path from the command line as below

```
python ReleaseTool.py -i C:\Users\Abdur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Exam System -o C:\Users\Abdur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Release
```

but it is throwing error

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''
```

due to 'Exam System' which has a space between.
Please suggest how to handle this.

Comment: try put `""` in your path. For example: `python ReleaseTool.py -i "C:\Users\Abdur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Exam System" -o C:\Users\Abdur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Release
`

Comment: its working.. thanks

Comment: Try this: `python ReleaseTool.py -i C:\Users\Abdur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\"Exam System" -o C:\Users\Abdur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Release`

Answer (score 6):

**Cause**

Long filenames or paths with spaces are supported by NTFS in Windows NT. However, these filenames or directory names require quotation marks around them when they are specified in a command prompt operation. Failure to use the quotation marks results in the error message.

**Solution**

Use quotation marks when specifying long filenames or paths with spaces. For example, typing the following at the command prompt
`copy c:\my file name d:\my new file name`
results in the following error message:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The correct syntax is:
`copy "c:\my file name" "d:\my new file name"`
Note that the quotation marks must be used.