# Im am getting FileNotFoundError when trying to create a for in loop

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I am making an `image classifier`. I have successfully created the folders and I manually placed the `.txt files` which has `links` to `images` from google inside each folder.

I am now trying to `download` the images from each `.txt file` `either` into a *folder inside each folder category*, `or` into *each category folder that also has the .txt file*, however i keep getting errors. please help.

I `manually` placed the `.txt files` in each of the folders as they was in the parent folder name as `PLANTS` but this has not made a difference.

I expected to get all the images downloaded in their respective folders from the .txt files with google image links but it is not working, whether the .txt is inside the main PLANTS FOLDER or inside each category folder which is inside the PLANTS folder

instead i get the below errors

FileNotFoundError

**please see attached screen shot**

[image]

&

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Long filenames or paths with spaces are supported by NTFS in Windows NT. However, these filenames or directory names require quotation marks around them when they are specified in a command prompt operation. Failure to use the quotation marks results in the error message.

```
 for i in range(len(folders)):
        path = "content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Flowers/PLANTS"
        #for creating directory we need path class object so below this: 
        dest_for_creating_directory = path/folders[i]
        #for searchi directory which have spaces we need doubleQuotations that  
        #why user below one in download image function instead of dest. 
        dest_for_searching_directory = path+"/"+folders[i]
```

> **Note:** its better practice to write folder/file name without `space` [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33717579/8138584)

Comment: is your code written in python? the code is in python

Comment: this is python yes. i have not declared variable name .. i just assigned the value . and for appending string we use concetenate operator in python.

Comment: can you write in the code in how you would want me to write it please.                                    for i in range(len(folders)):
  path = Path('content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Flowers/PLANTS')
  dest = path/folders[i]
  dest.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  links = Path(files[i])
  download_images(links, dest, max_pics=200)

Comment: @DarrenJay updated. check if it is working . is dest.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  is creating directory or not??  check that also

Comment: check that also and try to print dest variable show you can see what value dest has.

Comment: @DarrenJay i have explained again try this . i think you have not read the link i mentioned .  if  after this still you get error that remove spaces and use underscores in directory name.